# Adding Name to Hyperlink for Increase Curiosity

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am wanting to be able to add prospective client names to links on my site like.

> mydomainname.com/postname/Client Name

without the site throwing a 404 error.

Is there a simple way to do this?

most sites I will be doing this are wordpress based.

Comment: use `.htaccess` files for this

Answer (score 1):

I used this:
my htaccess file

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks  
    RewriteEngine On  

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

    RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

And this is to index.php

```
<?php  
  #remove the directory path we don't want 
  $request  = str_replace("mydomainname.com/", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 

  #split the path by '/'   
  $params     = split("/", $request);  
?>
```

After you get the params as an array.
I hope I can help!
Have fun!

Comment: Could this be accomplished for a wordpress post?